# Can we use egit in another RCP app?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, egit, jgit

I have an app that manages some files. I want to integrate git to this. Can I use EGit in this case? Or I must use JGit?

I'm trying to build egit but not yet successful. I just want to know if I can integrate EGit to my RCP app. Thank you!

Comment: If it is a 3.x compatibility mode RCP you should be able to include the egit plugins and whatever it depends on. It probably won't work in a pure e4 RCP.

Comment: To get an answer whether to use EGit or JGit, you should describe in more detail your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Jgit is basically the library which includes java implementation of git, Egit on the other hand, includes the UI part and the Jgit for the core git operations.

You can simply add the Egit plugin to your required plugins and it should work, if only your app is 3.X RCP based, I don't think it'll work in a pure RCP-4 application.